# Ruby Gems Area Not Writeable

Tags: ruby, rubygems, directory, chromebook

I am on a Acer Chromebook and installed Ruby and Git through the Chromebrew package manager. After this, I tried to install Sass through `gem install sass`. When I type this, I get `You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0 directory.`. I tried making another directory but cannot seem to. Help?

Update: When I try using `sudo gem install sass`, I get this error:

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EROFS)
    Read-only file system - /root/.gem`

Answer (score 0):

Try prepending `sudo` to your `gem install` command to install it with admin privileges: `sudo gem install sass`.